# Writing a program in Python using Turtle, drawings paste on top of each other

Tags: python

I'm creating a simple program that allows the user to draw a basic car in turtle a certain number of times. However, whenever a number higher than 1 is inputted, the cars stack on top of each other. I tried looking over my code and couldn't find any issues with it. Could someone please provide a solution? Here is the code

```
import turtle #allows use of turtle
import random #allows use of random

#program startup
s = turtle.Screen() #initializes screen
s.setup(1200, 800) #sets size of screen
s.colormode(255) #allows use of RGB
wow = turtle.Turtle() #initializes turtle and names it
wow.speed("fastest") #sets speed quick
s.bgcolor("grey") #sets floor color
wow.pencolor("yellow")
wow.pensize(5) #sets pen size
turtle.tracer(0, 0) #instantly draws everything

for x in range(1):
    wow.up()
    randX = random.randint(-600, 600)
    randY = random.randint(0, 400)
    wow.goto(400, 200)
    wow.down()
    #draws ship walls
    wow.left(90)
    wow.up()
    wow.goto(600, -200)
    wow.down()
    wow.color("black")
    wow.forward(1200)
    wow.down()
    wow.left(90)

for x in range (90):
    wow.forward(1200)
    wow.left(90)
    wow.forward(6)
    wow.left(90)
    wow.forward(1200)
    wow.right(90)
    wow.forward(6)
    wow.right(90)

shape = random.randint

def forward90():
    wow.forward(300)
    wow.left(90)


randomX = random.randint(100, 345)
randomY = random.randint(100, 345)

def starangles():
    for x in range(7):
        wow.pendown()
        #brings turtle forward
        wow.forward(10)
        #rotates it appropriately
        wow.right(144)
        wow.color("yellow")

def starlocation():
    wow.goto(randomX, randomY)

def star():
    starlocation()
    starangles()

#window
wow.begin_fill()
wow.pencolor("white")
wow.penup()
wow.goto(350, 350)
wow.pendown()
forward90()
forward90()
forward90()
forward90()
wow.color("black")
wow.end_fill()
wow.penup()
#wow.left(270)
#among us drawing

def upperbody():
    wow.color('#008000')
    wow.fillcolor('#008000')
    wow.penup()
    wow.goto(0,0)
    wow.pendown()
    wow.begin_fill()
    wow.forward(370)
    wow.left(90)
    wow.forward(50)
    wow.left(90)
    wow.forward(370)
    wow.left(90)
    wow.forward(50)
    wow.end_fill()

def doorandwindow():
    wow.penup()
    wow.goto(100, 50)
    wow.pendown()
    wow.setheading(45)
    wow.forward(70)
    wow.setheading(0)
    wow.forward(100)
    wow.setheading(-45)
    wow.forward(70)
    wow.setheading(90)
    wow.penup()
    wow.goto(200, 50)
    wow.pendown()
    wow.forward(49.50)

def tires():
    wow.penup()
    wow.goto(100, -10)
    wow.pendown()
    wow.color('#000000')
    wow.fillcolor('#000000')
    wow.begin_fill()
    wow.circle(20)
    wow.end_fill()
    wow.penup()
    wow.goto(300, -10)
    wow.pendown()
    wow.color('#000000')
    wow.fillcolor('#000000')
    wow.begin_fill()
    wow.circle(20)
    wow.end_fill()


wow.hideturtle() 

#car character number
y = int(s.numinput("Hello","How many cars do you want?"))

#loop as many times as inputted
for x in range(y):
    wow.setheading(0)
    randX = random.randint(-600, 600)
    randY = random.randint(-600, 600)
    wow.penup()
    wow.goto(randX, randY)
    wow.pendown()
    upperbody()
    doorandwindow()
    tires()

turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 1):

I see here

```
randX = random.randint(-600, 600) 
randY = random.randint(-600, 600)
```

That you are trying to randomize the location of your cars.
But the problem is all of your vehicle component methods have hardcoded the location to draw them at.

e.g.

```
def upperbody():
    wow.color('#008000')
    wow.fillcolor('#008000')
    wow.penup()
    wow.goto(0,0)
# here you can see that no matter where on the screen you call this function from,
# you will draw the upperbody at 0,0
    wow.pendown()
    wow.begin_fill()
    wow.forward(370)
    wow.left(90)
    wow.forward(50)
    wow.left(90)
    wow.forward(370)
    wow.left(90)
    wow.forward(50)
    wow.end_fill()
```

One solution would be to pass the location were you want the part to be as parameters, so your function header would look like
`def upperbody(x,y):`
of course you would then need to adjust the function accordingly